# How do I check if element exists with Mocha Chai Sinon?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, sinon-chai, teaspoon

I would like to know how can I check if an element on the UI exists by id or class. I'm using teaspoon-mocha, Sinon, and chai.

I tried next but it doesn't work:

```
expect($('my-id')).to.be.true;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be nice to have slightly more context, but generally speaking with jQuery you should check the length of array returned. And if you use an id the `'#'` sign must be there. Another thing is that the `.true` assertion in chai uses a strict `===` comparison (http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_true). So, either

```
expect($('#my-id').length === 1).to.be.true;
```

or

```
expect($('#my-id').length).to.be.ok;
```